# Handling errors on nuxt3 usefetch

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I just cant figure out how to handle errors here:

```
const { error, data } = useFetch('https://example.app/api/contact', {
   method: "POST",
   headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
   body: {
      name: form.name.value,
      email: form.email.value,
      message: form.message.value
   }
});
console.log(error.value, error)
```

On error itself it returns ref with _error that contains object with errors. However I cannot get to those errors anyhow..

Comment: Tried a `try/catch`?

Answer (score 10):

ref: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-fetch
useFetch return values {data, pending, error, refresh}, here is an example.

```js
const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch(
  'https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountains',
  {
    pick: ['title']
  }
)
```

BTW，useFetch return a **Promise**, in your example, you can do as follows.

```js
useFetch('https://example.app/api/contact', {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: {
    name: form.name.value,
    email: form.email.value,
    message: form.message.value
  }
}).then(res => {
  const data = res.data.value
  const error = res.error.value
  if (error) {
    // dealing error
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    console.log(data)
  }
}, error => {
  console.log('exception...')
  console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: second part is not working good (error => ...) but can be fixed to suit your needs

Answer (score 2):

As @Aborn Jiang stated, `useFetch` returns a Promise. The resolved `error`-property is a ref.

You could access the error details in Nuxt3 like this:

```js
const { error, data } = await useFetch('https://example.app/api/contact', {...});

console.log(error.value.data);
// Might be interesting as well:
console.log(error.value.name, error.value.message);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is a practical solution, you can do the console log after checking error, like this:

```
if (error.value) {
  console.log(error.value)
  throw createError({statusCode: 404, statusMessage: "Page 
 not found.", fatal: true})     
 }
```

You do not get *error* out, why console.log fails, you need to get the value after the error is trigged.

Comment: I have trouble understanding this phrasing "You do not get error out, why console.log fails, you need to get the value.". Please review for clarity and readability.

Comment: The questioner have:
console.log(error.value, error)

The error will not be proceed, as it is an object, but error.value will. It is basic programming knowlage.

Comment: Well, you get it, but it is not readable message. Nuxt is quite complicated. The thing is also if it is the server or the client who handle the error. If the server handle it, you need to do clearError(), to get console.log out.   I just tried to explain it in an easy way.