# Access JSON validation error response sent from Laravel API to Nuxt/Javascript app

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to print the validation errors in my Nuxt app, sent back from my Laravel API when validation fails.

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
  return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
}
```

In my Nuxt app I use useFetch

```
const response = await useFetch('/api/subscribers', {
  method: 'POST',
     body: {
        email: form.value.email
     }
})
```

If validation fails I get a 422, and I can see the errors in the console under the response tab.
But how do I access those in my Nuxt app? They exist nowhere inside the response-const.

However, if validation doesn't fail Laravel send back a 201 with a message instead

```
return response()->json(['message' => 'Everything good'], 201);
```

That message I *can* access through the response-const.

Why wouldn't I be able to access the errors the same way?

Comment: Please read this discussion (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71713419/handling-errors-on-nuxt3-usefetch) clearly and you will get to know details of error handling for `useFetch`.

Answer (score 0):

for 401 and maybe other errors(change 422 to 401), because you get no answer for you request you can add a code that if your response was not ok, do some function like this:

```
if(!response){
 /// do that
}
```

or you can do it in revese

```
if('Everything good' != response.message){
 /// do this
}
```